# Does singularity scheduler depends on CRON to schedule jobs?

Tags: scheduler, hubspot

I am evaluating different Job scheduling frameworks. One of the point of evaluation is scheduling framework. For example Spotify/Luigi uses CRON to schedule jobs and Airflow uses its own scheduler.
What does singularity internally use for scheduling jobs? (CRON or has its own scheduling framework)